# prevent zoom on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I using jQuery tabs structure on my website. 1 index file and another are included like tables.
But how to prevent zoom. Because users allowed zoom in/out
I have try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

but not working
IE-11

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [website](http://davidwalsh.name/zoom-mobile-browsers).

I tested this on my mobile device and could not zoom in.

They used this HTML META tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: `width=320` should be `width=device-width` and `user-scalable=0` should be `user-scalable=no`. Not sure if it matters but I've never seen anyone use 0 instead of 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding minimum-scale=1.0 there in meta tag property.